# Is this query for selecting MUTUAL FRIEND is CORRECT?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db('db2012');
    $uid = 8;
    $mid = 10;

    $q = mysql_query("select friend from users_friends where user = $uid") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0)
    {

        while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
        {
            $qq = mysql_query("select friend from users_friends where user = $mid") or die(mysql_error());
            while($rr = mysql_fetch_array($qq))
            {
                if($r[friend]==$rr[friend])
                {
                    $friend_name_query = mysql_query("select name from users where uid = '$rr[friend]'") or die();
                    $friend_name = mysql_fetch_array($friend_name_query);
                    echo $friend_name[name];
                }
            }
        }   
    }


?>
```

This query is working but any other way out  to use less queries ? i m a beginner programmer please let me know if there is n e thng ...

Comment: line 3 you have a single and a double quote just a quick observation.

Comment: If you are running a DB query in a loop, chances are it's the wrong way to do it. You should learn about [SQL `JOIN`s](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php). I fixed the quote issue mentioned by @Simon as I'm guessing this is a copy/paste error, otherwise you would be complaining of a parse error.

Comment: @Simon - think it's just a typo in the question, OP says his code is working but is asking if there's a more efficient way of achieving the same results.

Comment: YEAH IT DID WORKED BUT I HAD TO MAKE FEW CHANGES IN THAT..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use just one query:

```
$query = 'SELECT u.name
    FROM users_friends f1 
      INNER JOIN users_friends f2 ON (f2.friend = f1.friend)
      INNER JOIN user u ON (u.uid = f2.friend)
    WHERE f1.user = "'. $uid. '"
      AND f2.user = "'. $mid .'"';
```

run the query

```
$q = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

and do the while loop

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
  echo $r['name'];
}
```

You only need the `if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0)` statement if you do an `else`, otherwise you can just use the `while`

Comment: @Gulzar Ok can you please vote for the answer and set the answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: Here are some examples http://staging.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg AND http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&q=mysql+inner+join

Answer (score 0):

You could try below in order to get mutual friends of user 8 and 10.

```
select * from
user_friends a inner join user_friends b on
a.friend=b.friend and (a.user='8' and b.user='10')
```

U could then join the user table to get the name.